# Unexpected .GRP sequence in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Given a `data.table` such as:

```
library(data.table)
n = 5000
set.seed(123)
pop = data.table(id=1:n, age=sample(18:80, n, replace=TRUE))
```

and a function which converts a numeric vector into an ordered factor, such as:

```
toAgeGroups <- function(x){
  groups=c('Under 40','40-64','65+')
  grp = findInterval(x, c(40,65)) +1
  factor(groups[grp], levels=groups, ordered=TRUE)
}
```

I am seeing unexpected results when grouping on the output of this function as a key and indexing with `.GRP`.

```
pop[, .(age_segment_id = .GRP, pop_count=.N), keyby=.(age_segment = toAgeGroups(age))]
```

returns:

```
   age_segment age_segment_id pop_count
1:    Under 40              1      1743
2:       40-64              3      2015
3:         65+              2      1242
```

I would have expected the `age_segment_id` values to be `c(1,2,3)`, not `c(1,3,2)`, but `.GRP` seems set on order of occurrence in underlying data (as in `by=` order) rather than sorted order (as in `keyby=`).

I was planning on using `.GRP` as an index for some additional labelling, but instead I need to do something like:

```
pop[, .(pop_count=.N), keyby=.(age_segment = toAgeGroups(age))][, age_segment_id := .I][]
```

to get what I want.

Is this expected behavior?  If so, is there a better workaround?

(v. 1.9.6)

Comment: Your `toAgeGroups` function is subsumed by the `base` function `cut`, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue should no longer occur in versions 1.9.8+ of `data.table`.

```
library(data.table) #1.9.8+
pop[, .(age_segment_id = .GRP, pop_count=.N),
    keyby=.(age_segment = toAgeGroups(age))]
#    age_segment age_segment_id pop_count
# 1:    Under 40              1      1743
# 2:       40-64              2      2015
# 3:         65+              3      1242
```

For some more, see the discussion [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1880). Basically, how `by` works internally returns sorted rows for each group, then re-sorts the table back to its original order.

The change recognized that this re-sort is unnecessary if `keyby` is specified, so now your approach works as you expected.

Before (through 1.9.6), `keyby` would just re-sort the answer at the end by running `setkey`, as documented in `?data.table`:

> [`keyby` is the s]ame as `by`, but with an additional `setkey()` run on the `by` columns of the result.

Thus, on less-than-brand-new versions of `data.table`, you'd have to fix your code as:

```
pop[(order(age), .(age_segment_id = .GRP, pop_count=.N),
    keyby=.(age_segment = toAgeGroups(age))]
```

Comment: @MattDowle I guess this means the documentation should be tinkered?

Comment: Pinging @Arun as well.